# convert string to dateTime

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, localhost, typeconverter

in this [site](http://iranfairco.com/example/validDateTime.aspx)

It is very strange.

```
        DateTime a = DateTime.Parse("5/26/2011");
        Response.Write(a.ToShortDateString());
```

this code in localhost work fine.

But but but

on host say error:

String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

in this [site](http://iranfairco.com/example/validDateTime.aspx)

Comment: What's the culture set to for the website server?

Comment: That's because the server different locale, and cannot recognize the given format

Comment: to be sure from the income from the web, you espesificar "day", "month" and "year" and then convert it to this constructor http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/xcfzdy4x.aspx

Comment: i can not change setting website server

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `DateTime.ParseExact()`, it will allow you to specify your culture and format.

Here's an example using [InvariantCulture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4c5zdc6a.aspx):

```
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact("5/26/2011", 
                                        "MM/dd/yyyy", 
                                        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

And here's one that uses `en-US` specifically:

```
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact("5/26/2011", 
                                     "MM/dd/yyyy", 
                                     CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"));
```

Take a look at [the MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx).

Comment: +1: I think it's almost *always* a good idea to specify the format.

Comment: **Culture**. Meaning that in the en-US culture a date might be written `12/1/1981` for December 1st, 1980. But in France that date would be written `01/12/1981`.

Answer (score 1):

It's a culture-dependend error. Just pass the right culture to the [parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kc8s65zs.aspx) method:

```
DateTime a = DateTime.Parse("5/26/2011", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to reiterate Yuck and Sorantis's comments:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    foreach (CultureInfo ci in CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures))
    {
        try
        {
            DateTime.Parse("5/26/2011", ci);
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Able to parse with {0} CultureInfo object.", ci));
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Unable to parse with {0} CultureInfo object.", ci));
        }
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```